# My ReactJS initialState change when my state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, state, react-state-management

**I  have something like:**

```
const initialState={
 hide: true
 product:[
         {name: ''
          price: ''},
          {name: ''
          price: ''},
          {name: ''
          price: ''},
         ]
}

class Products extends Component {
  state = { ...initialState }

}
clearState = () =>{
  this.setState({...initialState})
}
```

I want to clear the state by using the initialState object, but when i try to do it nothing happens. I noticed that my initialState is taking the same values as my state, so,  when i execute other functions to edit the state, my initialState change too.

Any advice?
Thanks by the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial state is still storing a reference to the array, which means if you change the array anywhere else it will change everywhere.

To combat this problem, you could use a function that would create a new initialState for you to use, like this:

```js
const initialState = () => {
    return {
        hide: true,
        product: [
            {name: '', price: ''},
            {name: '', price: ''},
            {name: '', price: ''},
        ]
    };
};

class Products extends Component {
    state = initialState();

    clearState = () =>{
        this.setState(initialState());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand about javascript objects is that all their properties containing an object or an array will be only references...

That means that if you simple copy it using rest operator, the product array will be the same in all the cases...

The best way to achieve it would be creating a function to return the initial state, or a rude JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState)).

Comment: Oh, so that's it... I got the concept now. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

Taking Zeeh's answer, let's say you are using functional components, the best way to avoid these 2 variables being bound would be to do this:

```js
const initialState = {foo: 'bar'}
const [state,setState] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=>{
  setState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState)))
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking Crunchyman's answer:

Suppose you don't like to use JSON.parse followed by JSON.stringify. You can use the lodash deep clone solution

```
const initialState = {foo: 'bar'}
const [state,setState] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=>{
   setState(_.cloneDeep(initialState)))
},[])
```